# ExtJS/Javascript: adding a child Model to a parent Model, rendering this on a grid

Tags: javascript, json, model, store, extjs4.2

**Shorter Version:**
  I have a child model which I need to add to a parent model and then add to a store and render it within a grid, right now when I render it, it is displaying only the data from parent model and not the child model.
  In my controller, I believe the problem is around line 51: I dont know if there is any other way to do this,

```
company.set('employees',employees);
```

If I hardcode the data for my model, child ('Company' hasMany -> 'Employee') it renders fine in the grid. The model data I am trying to mimic is as below

```
data:{'items':[
   { 'col4': 'Dunder Miflin',  "col5":"A paper company",  "col6":"The Office", 
    "count" : 2,
    "employees": [{'col1': 'Michael Scott',  "col2":"michael@dundermiflin.com",  "col3":"555-111-1224" },
                  {'col1': 'Dwight Schrute',  "col2":"dwight@dundermiflin.com",  "col3":"555-222-1234"} ]
   },
   { 'col4': 'Athlead',  "col5":"Sports marketing company",  "col6":"The Office", 
     "count": 1,
         "employees": [{'col1': 'Jim Halpert',  "col2":"jim@athlead.com",  "col3":"555-222-4444"}]
   }

]}
```

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2efb
application code is under Assets/app/

When you load the fiddle, the second grid will already have 2 rows , this is the hardcoded data in the MainStore2.

In the top grid header, there is a button **'clickMe'**, on click it will read the records from MainStore (store of grid1) and group by Company and load col4,5,6 as Company model and col1,2,3 as child model Employee and adds array of Employees to Company model. So on button click it will add two more records to the lower grid, here it would display col4,5,6 but when you expand (+ - icon on the left), it is not displaying child employee rows unlike row 1 and 2. This is where my problem is. Adding array of child model to parent model.
In the end after clickMe event, row 3 and 4 should be same as row 1 & 2.

Any help or pointers is much appreciated.

**Detailed version:** (Read it only if you need more clarity to my problem)

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2efb
application code is under Assets/app/

[image]
I have 3 rows in the upper grid, it has two company, Dunder Miflin and Athlead. {col4}

On button Click ('**clickMe'** in the header) it would read this grid store, and group by Company (col4),

So on filter by col4,

1) I create a instance of 'Company' model, populate col4,5,6 to it , this will be Dunder Miflin, A Paper Company and The office respectively.

2) Loop through the records (there will be only 2 rows) , create Array of 'Employee' model and add col1,2,3 to it and add this array of employees to Company model as its child. This array will have,

[{Michael Scott, his email, his phonenumber},

{Dwight Schrute,his email, his phonenumber}]

On second filter, same as above but different Company (Athlead) and one employee(Jim).

Now add these two Company to a an Array and add this array of Company to the store pertaining to lower grid. Problem is that it is displaying Company but not Employee. In the end after clickMe event, row 3 and 4 should be same as row 1 & 2.

Pseudo code for above algorithm :

```
var companies = [];

Loop begin:
   var  company=Ext.create('TestUI.model.Company', record.data);
  var employees = [];
   var counter=0;

  //store1 filterByCol4.
  store1.each(function(record){
     var employeesModel = Ext.create('TestUI.model.Employee', record.data);
     employees.push(employeesModel.data);
 });
  company.set('employees',employees);
  companies.push(company);
loop END;

store2.add(companies);
store2.sync();
```

Any help or pointers is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally by trial n error figured how to add array of child model to a parent model.

'Company' model is my parent. hasMany relation with child model 'Employee'

```
Ext.define('TestUI.model.Company', {
    extend    : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields  : [
        {name: 'col4',        type: 'string'},
        {name: 'col5',        type: 'string'},
        {name: 'col6',        type: 'string'},
        {name: 'count',        type: 'int'}
    ]
    ,hasMany: [
         {model: 'TestUI.model.Employee',   name: 'employees'}
     ],
     proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});

Ext.define('TestUI.model.Employee', {
    extend    : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields  : [
        {name: 'col1',        type: 'string'},
        {name: 'col2',          type: 'string'},
        {name: 'col3',        type: 'string'}
    ],

     proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'employees'
        }
    }
});
```

And the magic line is :

```
company.employees().add(employees);
```

Pseudo code:

```
Loop through records and create employee model and add to employee array: {
   var employeesModel = Ext.create('TestUI.model.Employee', record.data);
   employees.push(employeesModel);
}
end Loop
//create Company model and add array employees to Company.
   var company=Ext.create('TestUI.model.Company', record.data);
   company.employees().add(employees);
```

Other change is I have moved the proxy from store to COmpany and Employee model.

updated working Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2efb